# How to map styles to Compose theme

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, relayjs, figma

I want to know how can I map a figma tokens to compose material tokens

[Topic](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling/relay/mapping-styles-to-compose-theme)
In the link above we have an information about mapping. But where can we get this file? Styles dictionary can't transform material style json to json file witch needed to relay android plugin. Can we write it mannually? Or can we have tool for it. If any one know how to work with it. Could you a little bit explane to me? I coudn't find enouth information about this feature.